# Changes to Oracle EM 11G Database Control "Availability >> Backup Settings" don't stick

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

Trying to configure Enterprise Manager 11G Database Control for backups for the first time. Whenever I navigate to

```
Availability >> Backup Settings >> Policy tab
```

and try to make a change, for example, enable the checkbox for `Automatically backup the control file and server parameter file (SPFILE) with every backup and database structural change`, then click `OK` button, the GUI says the settings were saved successfully, but when I revisit the page, it's always showing the default settings. (I make sure to set the correct Host Credentials at the bottom of the tab each time)

If I do it enough times, occasionally, the changes will stick the next time, but upon a 2nd (and subsequent) visits (without changing anything, just viewing the page), the settings go back to default again.

Anyone see this behavior before? The `Home` page doesn't show any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enterprise Manager 11.2.0.4 Database Control Backup Settings are not Retained, Scheduled Backups Fail to Run (Doc ID 2185136.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2185136.1)

> **SOLUTION**
>
> Download and apply one-off Patch 19316728 to the 11.2.0.4 database
>   Oracle Home according to the instructions in the associated README
>   file.

If you want to set the above setting manually, just log in to the server, and:

```
$ rman target /
RMAN> configure controlfile autobackup on;
```

Comment: Thank you @BalazsPapp! I applied the patch and it worked beautifully. You saved me so much time and headache. You rock!